# no action=transactResponse in Accept Hosted iframe for Authorize.net

Tags: iframe, authorize.net, accept.js

I'm trying to implement the Authorize.net Accept Hosted hosted checkout solution in a Coldfusion application.

(For all the ColdFusion developers, this code run on BlueDragon.NET 9 which a CF9 implementation.  The cfscript stacktrace support is terrible which is why this code is in tags and not in cfscript.)

Using our sandbox authorize.net account, the iframe hosted checkout page shows up.  I can fill out the credit card info and submit.  I get the receipt, 2 receipt emails from authorize.net and get sent to the confirmation page, but the case "transactResponse" in AuthorizeNetIFrame.onReceiveCommunication never gets triggered.  I put a alert in the javascript function to see all the querystrings that come into the iframe.

Other than the coldfusion code to authenticate and get the token (which seems to work) I got the rest of the code from the Authorize.net documentation.

Any idea why I don't see the action=transactResponse query string come into iframe with the response from the authorize.net credit card transaction.

I tried this with a live authorize.net account as well and I get a 'User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.'  on the iframe payment page even though I can authenticate and get a token for the iframe successfully.  What am I missing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Sensitive parts of the code (i.e. credentials), email, and address have been redacted.

Here is the main code file (this includes the iframe):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<head>
    <title>HostedPayment Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $("#btnOpenAuthorizeNetIFrame").click(function () {
                $("#add_payment").show();
                $("#send_token").attr({ "action": "https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment", "target": "add_payment" }).submit();
                $(window).scrollTop($('#add_payment').offset().top - 50);
            });

        });


</script>
</head>
<body>

<cfif NOT IsDefined("url.CFID") or NOT IsDefined("url.CFTOKEN")>
    <p style="color: red;">Error: CFID and CFTOKEN required as URL parameters...</p>
    <cfabort />
</cfif>

<cfinclude template="../#client.custom_path#/constants.cfm" />

<cfset variables.LOGIN_TOKEN_URL = "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api" />
<cfset variables.API_LOGIN_ID = "ZZZZZZZZZZZ" />
<cfset variables.TRANSACTION_KEY = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" />

<h2>Authenticate</h2>

<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.soapBody">
<authenticateTestRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>#variables.API_LOGIN_ID#</name>
        <transactionKey>#variables.TRANSACTION_KEY#</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
</authenticateTestRequest>
</cfsavecontent>
</cfoutput>

<cfhttp url="#variables.LOGIN_TOKEN_URL#"
    method="post"
    result="variables.result1">
    <cfhttpparam
        type="xml"
        value="#Trim( variables.soapBody )#"
        />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#variables.result1#" />

<cfset variables.response1 = XMLParse(Trim(Right(variables.result1.filecontent, Len(variables.result1.filecontent)-1))) />
<cfset variables.response = StructNew() />

<cfset variables.response.resultCode = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result1.filecontent, Len(variables.result1.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'resultCode' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.response.resultCode[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.response.resultCode = variables.response.resultCode[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfset variables.response.code = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result1.filecontent, Len(variables.result1.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'code' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.response.code[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.response.code = variables.response.code[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfset variables.response.text = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result1.filecontent, Len(variables.result1.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'text' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.response.text[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.response.text = variables.response.text[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined("variables.response.text") AND FindNoCase("Successful", variables.response.text)>
    <p style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">Success</p>
<cfelse>
    <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Failure</p>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#variables.response#" />
<cfdump var="#variables.response1#" />

<h2>Get token</h2>

<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent variable="variables.soapBody2">
<getHostedPaymentPageRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>#variables.API_LOGIN_ID#</name>
    <transactionKey>#variables.TRANSACTION_KEY#</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>0.01</amount>
    <customer>
      <email>ZZZZZZZZ@ZZZZZZZZ.com</email>
    </customer>
    <billTo>
        <firstName>ZZZZZZZZ</firstName>
        <lastName>Tester1</lastName>
        <company></company>
        <address>123 Main Street</address>
        <city>ZZZZZZZZ</city>
        <state>ZZ</state>
        <zip>22222</zip>
        <country>US</country>
    </billTo>
  </transactionRequest>
  <hostedPaymentSettings>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentReturnOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"showReceipt": true, "url": "https://ZZZZZZZZ.com/test/hosted_pages/cart_hosted_confirm.cfm", "urlText": "Continue", "cancelUrl": "https://ZZZZZZZZ.com/test/hosted_pages/cart_hosted_cancel.cfm", "cancelUrlText": "Cancel"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentButtonOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"text": "Pay"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentStyleOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"bgColor": "blue"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentPaymentOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"cardCodeRequired": true, "showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentSecurityOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"captcha": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": false, "required": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": true, "required":true}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentCustomerOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"showEmail": true, "requiredEmail": true, "addPaymentProfile": false}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentOrderOptions</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"show": true, "merchantName": "Test Company, LLC"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
    <setting>
      <settingName>hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl</settingName>
      <settingValue>{"url": "https://ZZZZZZZZ.com/test/hosted_pages/IFrameCommunicator.html"}</settingValue>
    </setting>
  </hostedPaymentSettings>
</getHostedPaymentPageRequest>
</cfsavecontent>
</cfoutput>

<cfhttp url="#variables.LOGIN_TOKEN_URL#"
    method="post"
    result="variables.result2">
    <cfhttpparam
        type="xml"
        value="#Trim( variables.soapBody2 )#"
        />
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#variables.result2#" />

<cfset variables.response2 = XMLParse(Trim(Right(variables.result2.filecontent, Len(variables.result2.filecontent)-1))) />
<cfset variables.responseToken = StructNew() />

<cfset variables.responseToken.resultCode = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result2.filecontent, Len(variables.result2.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'resultCode' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.resultCode[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.responseToken.resultCode = variables.responseToken.resultCode[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfset variables.responseToken.code = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result2.filecontent, Len(variables.result2.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'code' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.code[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.responseToken.code = variables.responseToken.code[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfset variables.responseToken.text = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result2.filecontent, Len(variables.result2.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'text' ]"
    ) />
<cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.text[1].XmlText")>
    <cfset variables.responseToken.text = variables.responseToken.text[1].XmlText />
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.text") AND FindNoCase("Successful", variables.responseToken.text)>
    <p style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">Success</p>
    
    <cfset variables.responseToken.token = xmlSearch(Trim(Right(variables.result2.filecontent, Len(variables.result2.filecontent)-1)),
    "//*[ local-name() = 'token' ]"
    ) />
    <cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.token[1].XmlText")>
        <cfset variables.responseToken.token = variables.responseToken.token[1].XmlText />
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Failure</p>
</cfif>

<cfdump var="#variables.response2#" />
<cfdump var="#variables.responseToken#" />

<h2>Hosted Page</h2>
<cfif IsDefined("variables.responseToken.token") AND Len(Trim(variables.responseToken.token)) GT 0>

    <div>
    Open Authorize.net in an iframe to complete transaction
    <button id="btnOpenAuthorizeNetIFrame" onclick="">Show Payment Form</button>
    </div>
    <div id="iframe_holder" class="center-block" style="width:90%;max-width: 1000px">
    <iframe id="add_payment" class="embed-responsive-item panel" name="add_payment" width="100%"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" hidden="true">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    <cfoutput>
    <form id="send_token" action="" method="post" target="add_payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="#variables.responseToken.token#" />
    </form> 
    </cfoutput>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            if (!window.AuthorizeNetIFrame) window.AuthorizeNetIFrame = {};
                AuthorizeNetIFrame.onReceiveCommunication = function (querystr) {
                
                    alert('processing 1:'+querystr);
                    
                    var params = parseQueryString(querystr);
                        switch (params["action"]) {
                            case "successfulSave":
                                break;
                            case "cancel":
                                break;
                            case "resizeWindow":
                                var w = parseInt(params["width"]);
                                var h = parseInt(params["height"]);
                                var ifrm = document.getElementById("add_payment");
                                ifrm.style.width = w.toString() + "px";
                                ifrm.style.height = h.toString() + "px";
                                break;
                            case "transactResponse":
                                var ifrm = document.getElementById("add_payment");
                                ifrm.style.display = 'none';
                                
                                var formData = { gatewayResponse: params["response"] };
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "cart_hosted_async_log.cfm?<cfoutput>#URLTOKEN#</cfoutput>",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: formData,
                                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                                    {},
                                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                                    {}
                                });
                                break;
                            }
                    };

                function parseQueryString(str) {
                    var vars = [];
                    var arr = str.split('&');
                    var pair;
                    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        pair = arr[i].split('=');
                        vars.push(pair[0]);
                        vars[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
                        }
                    return vars;
                    }
        }());
    </script>
</cfif>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the IFrameCommunicator.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Iframe Communicator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            function callParentFunction(str) {
                if (str && str.length > 0 
                    && window.parent 
                    && window.parent.parent
                    && window.parent.parent.AuthorizeNetIFrame 
                    && window.parent.parent.AuthorizeNetIFrame.onReceiveCommunication)
                    {
// Errors indicate a mismatch in domain between the page containing the iframe and this page.
                        window.parent.parent.AuthorizeNetIFrame.onReceiveCommunication(str);
                    }
                }

            function receiveMessage(event) {
                if (event && event.data) {
                    callParentFunction(event.data);
                    }
                }

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
                    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                        window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
                    }

                if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash.length > 1) {
                    callParentFunction(window.location.hash.substring(1));
                    }
        //]]/>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html,
under Transaction Response is the following note:

> Important: If you host the form in an iframe, you must include the
> iframe communicator URL in the hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl
> parameter of your getHostedPaymentPageRequest API call. To ensure that
> you receive a response code, **you must also set showReceipt to
> false.**

Bolding added by me. After setting `showReceipt` to `false`, I get the response against my Sandbox account.

For the error:

> 'User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.'

I found out my answer from Authorize.net support.  It occurs when your site/software sends a request for a payment or creation of a profile to Authorize.Net via the API and we don’t recognize the API Login ID and Transaction Key that were submitted in the request. There are only three possible causes of this error:

1. Your site/software is posting to a live account's API Login ID and Transaction Key while using the test environment URL at https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api -- For live accounts, please ensure your site/software is posting to https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api instead.
2. Your site/software is posting to a test account's API Login ID and Transaction Key while using the live environment at https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api -- For test accounts, please post to https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api instead.
3. Your site/software is using an incorrect API Login ID or Transaction Key. If this is the case then we suggest to verify your API Login ID on the Authorize.Net portal or generate a new Transaction Key if needed. You can use this site as well on how to verify/generate these: https://support.authorize.net/s/article/What-Are-the-API-Login-ID-and-Transaction-Key

In my case I found the token was being sent to https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment not https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment.  Changed it and now the code works.